NextAuth 5.0 + Next 14 - Transmitting authentication data during API calls
How can I include authentication when making fetch calls? I'm not receiving session information in the API route.
page.tsx
export default async function page() {
  const response = await fetch(`/api/module`);
}

/api/module/route.ts
import { auth } from "@/auth"

export async function GET(request: NextRequest, response: NextRequest) {
  // session is null
  const session = await auth();
}

